# WYSIWYG editor for transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.8, email, wysiwyg

What's the best way to enable a WYSIWYG editor for transactional emails? I would of thought this feature came natively with Magento but it doesn't seem that way

I have found the following free extension however I have heard bad things about it so wanted to see if there is something better
http://urthemes.com/magento-wysiwyg-editor-for-transactional-emails.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to keep in mind when using WYSIWYG for transactional e-mails:

- Sending out HTML e-mails which can be viewed in a nice way in multiple e-mail clients is not always fun & easy: There are some "specialities" from mail client to mail client that need to be taken care of
- It could mess up your e-mail design and won't benefit some special adaptions as mentioned above
- You're limited to the WYSIWYG functions in your e-mail template. When I think of adding conditions like `{{depend object.function()}} .... {{depend}}` this can't be inserted with an WYSIWYG anyway.
- It will not work with responsive e-mail templates as you would not be able to edit reponsive e-mails with a WYSIWYG editor
- The WYSIWYG editor will try to interpret layout handles `{{var items_html}}` as widget instances which can cause problems (thanks to @SanderMangel for pointing that out).

I would not say that's impossible, if you find the ultimate WYSIWYG editor for transactional e-mails that does not cause problems, tell us :-)